# How to get php 7 on mac?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, php

I want to upgrade my php from php5 to php7. I want to do it through the terminal and I just cant figure out how.

Does anyone have a step by step guide on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use homebrew and [homebrew-php](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php):

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
brew install php70
```

Comment: Additionally, you can install Homebrew from [here](http://brew.sh/).